# Applications acts differently locally and on shiny server pro

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a set of codes. (sorry cannot produce it since it is huge). But this acts properly locally. But when deployed on shiny server pro, it is not working.

I checked all libraries that are loaded are of same version.

One question, even if libraries are not loaded and there version are different between local and shiny server. Will this effect the application?

Comment: Yes it may affect your apps, all should be in sync. Use the same versions of the libraries

Comment: Just to double check. The libraries that are not loaded also should have same versions :) this is what you meant?

Comment: under the hood, you have `shiny`, you have `Rcpp` and others, the logs will tell you what is wrong

Comment: Great. Can you let me know how to check logs. I am new to shiny server pro.

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003717168-Shiny-Server-Error-Logs